# Confusion between Word16 and UWord16

Tags: c#, c, porting

I'm porting some C code to C#. I'm seeing a lot of `Word16`, `Word32` usage, along with `UWord16`and `UWord32`.

I know `Word32` is an unsigned 32bit `int` type, but what could have been the need to write it with a different name `UWord32`? Am I missing something here? Is it different from `Word32` in some manner?

Also, `WORD32` can I just replace its usage in C# with `int`? If not, why?

**[This Source](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Data-Word.html)**, says WORD is an unsigned integral type.  Yes the source is of Haskell, I couldn't find any other documentation explaining the datatype `WORD`.

Comment: There are definitely too many tags under this question.

Comment: Your link is Haskell, but you're tags are C/C++...?

Comment: I couldn't find any other Word documentation. @ReedCopsey

Comment: @SeanVaughn You need to look at the header defining that type, in your C or C++ code, to see how it's defined.  I listed the standard Windows API data types in my answer, but they're different - `WORD` can mean anything in C or C++.

Comment: The meaning of "word" in the context of an integral datatype is not standardised. When you say _"I know `Word32` is an unsigned 32bit int type"_, do you know this because you've inspected the source typedefs? Because given the existence of `UWord32` I'd assume that `Word32` is signed.

Comment: I didn't knew that @Rook, I thought Word has a static defination just like other primitive data types, not I know that I was wrong.

Comment: @SeanVaughn: no primitives have a static definition.  `long` varies between linux and windows, some older machines have 32-bit `char`s...

Comment: but atleast you can figure out the data size of the primitives regarding the machine for which the code is written. For example, I can say `int` will a of 16bits for older 16bit processors. @MooingDuck

Comment: @SeanVaughn: The Standard does not make that guarantee. Also, I downvoted you. You're porting C code- this does not require a C++ tag, your link to Haskell documentation is thoroughly irrelevant, and people have a perfect right to downvote your question. It's not bullying- it's a fundamental mechanism of the site to downvote. Downvoting exists for a good reason and your bolded text just makes this question look so bad.

Comment: And instead of directing me to edit it, you simply downvoted? @DeadMG

Comment: Do you see my rep @DeadMG, I'm new here, sorry I'm not aware of all the customs here and sorry I couldn't match up to your standards. I'm really very sorry, from the deepest core of my heart.

Comment: @SeanVaughn - downvotes happen. As it is you have five upvotes for an increase of 50 rep and three downvotes for a loss of 6 rep, so you're up 44 which is better than 50% of your rep. Sounds fair to me. YMMV.

Comment: Downvotes shouldn't happen if they are not needed @BobJarvis. And you are correct for what you said, but people with high rep here don't show any mercy to the new people here, and this thing leads to starvation. It seems more of an egoistic downvote, "Hey, the tag is wrong, let's downvote.". And I must mention, many times downvotes lead to blocking of account, so downvotes should not be played with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but what could have been the need to write it with a different name UWord32?

This is an unsigned 32 bit integer type.

In general, you can likely replace (moving to C#):

`WORD32` -> `int`  (`Int32`)

`UWORD32` -> `uint` (`UInt32`)

`WORD16` -> `short`  (`Int16`)

`UWORD16` -> `ushort`  (`UInt16`)

This is, however, all speculation based on my expectations given the naming scheme you've shown.

Note that, if you're using [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `WORD` -> `ushort`, and `DWORD` -> `uint`.  Signed types are `INT`/`INT32` -> `int`, and then `INT16` -> `short`, `INT64` -> `long`, etc.

That being said, **all** of these options are all defines in C or C++, and not "native" (language defined) types.  Your code could define `WORD` to represent an unsigned 64 bit integer, if it chose.  As such, you need to look at where the defines are coming from (I listed the Windows API standards here).

---

> I know Word32 is an unsigned 32bit int type, but what could have been the need to write it with a different name UWord32?

If this is the case, there is likely no need to have two definitions for the same type.  It may be that two headers you are using define things slightly different.  Again, you'd need to check the headers you're using that define these types, and see how they're specified.

Comment: [source](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Data-Word.html), says `WORD` is an unsigned integral type. And you should wait before downvoting a question and try to understand what it wants to say first.

Comment: @SeanVaughn I didn't downvote, actually - but that source is for haskell, not C or C++...  Typically, if you're porting code that has `WORD32` and `UWORD32`, then `WORD` would be signed and `UWORD` unsigned.  It depends on where you're getting your defines, though.

Comment: @SeanVaughn - the link you posted is to the Haskell programming language web site.  Please explain how Haskell relates to this question.  In C, which is what your question is tagged for, experienced developers would expect Word16 to be a signed 16-bit integer, and UWord16 to be an unsigned 16-bit integer.  If your question refers to Haskell please tag it as such, and edit your post to explain what you're doing.  Thanks.

Comment: I explained it in above POST's comments @BobJarvis, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @BobJarvis That was my thought - given `Word32` and `UWord32`, I'd *expect* signed/unsigned - though a developer is allowed to do anything they chose.